# $\forall v \in \mathbb R^n , v^tAv \ge 0 $ then $Au=\theta$ iff $A^tu=\theta$?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A$ be a real matrix of size $n$ such that for every vector (column matrix) $v \in \mathbb R^n$ , $v^tAv\ge 0$ , then is it true that $Au=\theta$ iff $A^tu=\theta$ ? where $\theta$ is the null vector

Comment: Don't quite understand the title. How is $v$ related to $A$?

Comment: Should it be $Au=\theta$ iff $A^tu=-\theta$?

Comment: @John: Is it clear now ?

Comment: Much better. So basically, $A$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: @orion: I don't know those things

Answer (score 0):

$v^tAv\geq0\Rightarrow v^t(A^t+A)v\geq0\Rightarrow A^t+A$ is semi-positive definite. So there exist some invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^t(A^t+A)P=
\begin{bmatrix}
     I_k & 0 \\
     0 & 0  
  \end{bmatrix}$.

So $Au=0\Rightarrow 0=u^t(A^t+A)u= 
u^t(P^{-1})^tP^t(A^t+A)PP^{-1}u=(P^{-1}u)^t\begin{bmatrix}
     I_k & 0 \\
     0 & 0  
  \end{bmatrix}P^{-1}u\Rightarrow P^{-1}u=\begin{bmatrix}
     0\\
     \alpha   
  \end{bmatrix}\Rightarrow P^t(A^t+A)PP^{-1}u=0\Rightarrow(A^t+A)u=0\Rightarrow A^tu=0$.
If $A^tu=0$, we can obtain $Au=0$ similarly.